# How many "2-times" exist between two given digital times

Tags: combinatorics

We are given two times in the format HH:MM:SS, where HH is from 00-23, MM is 00-59, and SS is 00-59. A time is considered "two-time" if it can be written with at most 2 distinct digits. For example, 11:11:12 and 14:14:14 are both valid two-times. How many valid two-times are there between two given times, inclusive? For instance, if 11:11:11 and 11:11:15 are given, then there are 6 total values (each time between and including those two).

I have to code this, but I was wondering if there is was a neat mathematical intuition behind it.

Comment: Just code this... it is testing your ability to understand how to write `for` loops.

Comment: Write some function $f(t)$ that calculates the number of 2-times between 00:00:00 and a given time $t$. Then use this to calculate what the problem asks you as the difference of $f(t_2) - f(t_1-1s)$